# How can I change the default Control template of a TabControl according to my choice

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

I am trying to develop a Customize TabControl in which I'll divide the Whole TabControl into three Parts:

1)Tab Header
2)Common Region(for all Tab) and 
3)Tab Content region for specific Tab
Update:
 [image]

Please provide your best answers or samples if you have then, any type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are trying to develop a custom tab control however I'm confused by your question. Are you going to post code you need help with or do you just want someone to develop it for you?

Comment: I need help by the mean of idea, example, knowledge or anything whatever the way by which some one can help me that's it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the TabControl Template to be anything you want, including making it have a static region that stays visible regardless of which tab is selected.

Within the Template, I normally use a panel with `IsItemsHost=True` to define where the "Tab" portion of the tab control will be displayed and `<ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />` where I want the selected tab content to be displayed.

The `TabControl.ItemTemplate` can also be overwritten to further define your Tabs, and `TabControl.ItemContainer` can be overwritten to modify just the TabContent part of the TabControl.

Comment: Thank you a lot Rachel it is what I am looking for. But if I'll overwrite the TabContent and if I modified the TabContent region with two parts then While I'll load the Content are for specific tab then every time I have to load the Both the divided regions which I don't want. Do you have any idea how to use this without loading whole the TabContent area again and again ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... the static area should be part of the TabControl's `ControlTemplate`, not the SelectedTab. The only part that gets reloaded when switching tabs is the `ContentPresenter` area of the Tab's ControlTemplate. Your static content probably shouldn't be in this area.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... I don't quite understand why one would do this, but if I were you I would implement this using WPF.

I would implement the tab header as a StackPanel filled with Buttons (their style obviously needs to be redone so that it looks like tabs). The content would be a rectangle containing a grid whose content changes on clicking a button. And that's pretty much it for the basic sceleton. I don't understand your Common Region. What is also nice is to add a little "X" inside each tab in order to close it. That can be done with buttons as well.

It might make sense to use Expression Blend to create such a control.

Best wishes,
Christian

Comment: Thanks for your keen interest on my Application, by the way I want to use tabs at the 1st region i.e. at the Header position and some common controls at the Second region which will be accessible from any of the tab and its functionality will be same for all tab. 3rd region for specific content for specific tab means if the user will click on Tab1 then Tab1 content will show on the Third region, that's it